# Does PHP grok null references?

Tags: php, reference, null

I want to define a PHP function with an reference parameter, by default, a null reference. Not very much unlike what the following C++ code would do:

```
ReturnType my_function(moar lulz, ParameterType* ptr_to_my_param = 0)
{
    // do some processing using lulz only
    // ...

    if (ptr_to_my_param)
    {
        // use *ptr_to_my_param
        // or   ptr_to_my_param->
        // ...
    }

    // do more processing, again using lulz only
    // ...
}
```

How do I do that in PHP?

Comment: In PHP it is not possible to detect if a passed parameter is a reference or not. You can only test for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do something like

```
class NiceClass {}

function foo($baz, NiceClass $bar = NULL) {

    // Do some processing

    if(bar !== NULL) {
         // Do something with bar
         $bar->yay($baz);
    }

    // Do some more processing
}
```

Comment: Yes... except for a point. I want to pass a null reference (in the C sense of the word "reference") to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_function($value, $value = null) {
  if(is_null($value)) {

  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: I want an optional output parameter of type integer. I really miss .NET's `Nullable<T> where T : struct`